# WiFi adapter is delaying packets when low throughput

Tags: network-interface

I was testing a WebSocket connection when I noticed jitter; some TCP packets were getting delayed. So I started pinging the destination. The TCP packets were no longer getting delayed. I stopped pinging; I started getting jitter again.

It seems like that if I have a certain threshold of traffic then the network adapter no longer has jitter, below that threshold however it seems to delay packets.

I tested it again by pinging other sites unrelated to the WebSocket connection path and that too removes the jitter. It also happens regardless of the traffic and path e.g if I stream data from a different destination and test the WS connection there's no jitter. This seems to indicate it's specific to the local network interface as that's the only constant here.

*It appears to me like the local network adapter is going into a 'sleepy/low-power' state if there's not much traffic. Is this possible? Is there any way to diagnose or investigate this?*

Comment: What's your wireless MTU?

Comment: Wireless MTU is 1500

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by active power management on the Wireless NIC.

Running this command which switches off power management for the NIC fixed this:

```
sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off
```

It seems the power management for this particular NIC became active with an extremely low timeout. E.g no traffic transmitted for ~200 ms will put the NIC into low power mode. This meant that the NIC was constantly having to be woken up at low traffic volumes resulting in delayed packets.